# fastapi throws 400 bad request when I upload a large file

Tags: file-upload, fastapi, httpx

I provisioned and configured a Fedora 34 vm on VirtualBox with 2048 MB RAM to serve this FastAPI application on `localhost:7070`. The full application source code and dependency code and instructions are [here](https://github.com/mfleader/snappy-data-server). Below is the smallest reproducible example I could make.

`main.py`

```
import os, pathlib

import fastapi as fast
import aiofiles

        
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
RESULTS_DIR = pathlib.Path('/'.join((ROOT_DIR, 'results')))

    
app = fast.FastAPI()

    
@app.post('/api')
async def upload(
    request: fast.Request, 
    file: fast.UploadFile = fast.File(...),
    filedir: str = ''):
        
    dest = RESULTS_DIR.joinpath(filedir, file.filename)
    dest.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    async with aiofiles.open(dest, 'wb') as buffer:
        await file.seek(0)
        contents = await file.read()
        await buffer.write(contents)

    return f'localhost:7070/{dest.parent.name}/{dest.name}'
```

`start.sh` the server application

```
#! /bin/bash
uvicorn --host "0.0.0.0" --log-level debug --port 7070 main:app
```

`client.py`

```
import httpx
from pathlib import Path
import asyncio

async def async_post_file_req(url: str, filepath: Path):    
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(
        timeout=httpx.Timeout(write=None, read=None, connect=None, pool=None)) as client:
        r = await client.post(
            url, 
            files={
                'file': (filepath.name, filepath.open('rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
            }
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://localhost:7070'
    asyncio.run(
        async_post_file_req(
            f'{url}/api',            
            Path('~/1500M.txt')
    ))
```

create a 1500 MB file

```
truncate -s 1500M 1500M.txt
```

When uploading a 1500 MB file, the current implementation of `upload` appears to read the whole file into memory, and then the server responds with `{status: 400, reason: 'Bad Request', details: 'There was an error parsing the body.'}`, and the file is not written to disk. When uploading an 825 MB file, the server responds with 200, and the file is written to disk. I don't understand why there is an error in parsing the larger file.

What's going on?

How do I upload files that are larger than the machine's available memory?

Do I have to stream the body?

Comment: `UploadFile` should spool to disk automagically when exceeding `1024*1024` bytes (so 1MB) according to Starlette's source code: https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/5ee04ef9b1bc11dc14d299e6c855c9a3f7d5ff16/starlette/datastructures.py#L425 . The Starlette implementation supports a `file` parameter with the io object to use for storing files, but I haven't digged further into how you can use that with `File()`

Comment: It does spool to disk, but that is bound by the space available to the device on which your temporary directory lives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upload a large File (≥3GB) to FastAPI backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73442335/how-to-upload-a-large-file-%e2%89%a53gb-to-fastapi-backend)

Answer (score 7):

Digging into the source code, I found that FastAPI is throws the HTTP exception with status code 400 and detail `There was an error in parsing body` [exactly once](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/22528373bba6a654323de416ad5c867cbadb81bb/fastapi/routing.py#L189) in the source code, when it is trying to figure out if the request form or body needs to be read. The [FastAPI Request is basically the Starlette Request](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/22528373bba6a654323de416ad5c867cbadb81bb/fastapi/requests.py#L2), so I reimplemented the FastAPI server application as a Starlette application hoping it would bypass this exception handler and give me more information about this issue.

`main.py`

```py
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from starlette.routing import Route
async def homepage(request):
    return JSONResponse({'hello': 'world'})
async def upload(request):
  form = await request.form()
  print(type(form['upload_file']))
  filename = form['upload_file'].filename or 'not found'
  contents = await form['upload_file'].read()
  b = len(contents) or -1
  return JSONResponse({
    'filename': filename,
    'bytes': b
  })
app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=[
    Route('/', homepage),
    Route('/api', upload, methods=['POST'])
])
```

`Pipfile`

```sh
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
starlette = "*"
uvicorn = "*"
uvloop = "*"
httpx = "*"
watchgod = "*"
python-multipart = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

On posting a file of size 989 MiB or larger, the Starlette application throws OS error 28, no space left on device. A file of size 988 MiB or less, caused no error.

```sh
INFO:     10.0.2.2:46996 - "POST /api HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 398, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/star-file-server/./main.py", line 11, in upload
    form = await request.form()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 240, in form
    self._form = await multipart_parser.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/formparsers.py", line 231, in parse
    await file.write(message_bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py", line 445, in write
    await run_in_threadpool(self.file.write, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/tempfile.py", line 755, in write
    rv = file.write(s)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

[Starlette's UploadFile data structure](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b6f3578bb2cf6c60e3efe110143409b47f368d36/starlette/datastructures.py#L433) uses a [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile). This object writes to your [os's temporary directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir). My temporary directory is `/tmp` because I'm on Fedora 34, and I have not created any environment variables to tell python to use anything else as a temporary directory.

```sh
[vagrant@fedora star-file-server]$ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 14 2021, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 11.1.1 20210428 (Red Hat 11.1.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile.gettempdir()
'/tmp'
```

```sh
[vagrant@fedora star-file-server]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        974M     0  974M   0% /dev
tmpfs           989M  168K  989M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           396M  5.6M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        40G  1.6G   36G   5% /
tmpfs           989M     0  989M   0% /tmp
tmpfs           198M   84K  198M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Starlette sets `max_size` for the `SpooledTemporaryDirectory` to 1 MiB. From the Python tempfile documentation, I think that means only 1 MiB can be read into memory at a time from the temporary file while it is being used. Although it is of by 1 MiB, 989 MiB appears to be the correct hard boundary on the `UploadFile` size because `SpooledTemporaryDirectory` is bound by the storage available to the system's temporary directory.

If I still want to use `UploadFile` I can create an environment variable to point to a device that is known to always have enough space available, even for the largest uploads.

```sh
export TMPDIR=/huge_storage_device
```

The approach I prefer uses the request's `stream`, to avoid having to write the file  twice, first to a local temporary directory, and second to a local permanent directory.

```py
import os, pathlib

import fastapi as fast
import aiofiles

app = fast.FastAPI()


@app.post('/stream')
async def stream(
    request: fast.Request,
    filename: str,
    filedir: str = ''
):

    dest = RESULTS_DIR.joinpath(filedir, filename)
    dest.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)        

    async with aiofiles.open(dest, 'wb') as buffer:       
        async for chunk in request.stream():
            await buffer.write(chunk)

    return {
        'loc': f'localhost:7070/{dest.parent.name}/{dest.name}'
    }
```

Using this approach, when I uploaded files (5M, 450M, 988M each with two repeated measures) to the server running on a Fedora vm with 2048 MiB memory, the server never used up too much memory, never crashed, and the average latency reduction was 40% (i.e. the latency of posting to `/stream` was about 60% of latency posting to `/api`).