# fastapi cannot upload file larger than 1MB

Tags: fastapi

I create a basic upload example as below. It works fine if the file size is less than 1MB, but got a 400 bad request, "detail": "There was an error parsing the body" once the file size is larger than 1MB. I have installed the python-multipart package.

```
from typing import List
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File

app = FastAPI(debug=True)


@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
async def create_upload_files(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filenames": file.filename}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712596/fastapi-throws-400-bad-request-when-i-upload-a-large-file

Comment: Thanks, it works using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712596/fastapi-throws-400-bad-request-when-i-upload-a-large-file's solution!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the version of anyio python package. Consider using versions >= 3.4.0.